# Ionic 3 get file from Google Drive using uri

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic 3.13.1 framework. My application should allow user to work with files from device and from google drive. I am using [IonicNativeFile](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) and [IonicNativeFileChooser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/). So, when I select file from device memory - all works good, but I cannot use that method for google drive files. My function looks like:

```
public OpenFile(event: Event) {
   this.fileChooser.open() //Open File Chooser
  .then(uri => { //get uri
    console.log(`URI: ${uri}`);
    ( < any > window).FilePath.resolveNativePath(uri, (result) => { //Get file path in storage from uri
      this.nativepath = result;
      console.log(`Native Path: ${this.nativepath}`);
      this.readFile(); //read data from file
      this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({ //Create and show loader message
        content: "Loading..."
      });
      this.loader.present();
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(`Looks like file from GDrive: code ${error.code} message ${error.message}`);        
    });
  }).catch(e => console.log(e));}
```

The uri is: content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3Di2Alapnkehx4uFSbuS2U3VO_rC-nrHu3Emq8u8eF4Z9w8QvL%0A

ResolveNativePath shoud return 1 if file is in cloud, but my function returns 0 with message: Unable to resolve filesystem path. I dont't know how to fix it. 
Help me, please. What should I do to get path of file?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @ACES, no, I didn't :(

Comment: I did... using FilePath plugin @Polly do you need help with it?

Comment: @ACES, can you post your solution as an answer?